# Python telegram-bot: Prompt for another input

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a bot in Python that prompts the user to pick from a list of IDs to change and the idea is that the user will select the ID and then supply the ID they want to change to.

Here is my code:

```
def build_menu(buttons, n_cols):
    menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
    return menu

def change_process(bot, update):
    global action
    query = update.callback_query
    NAME = query.data
    if action == 'Change':
        # Prompt user for new value
        # run sql query to update 

def change(bot, update, args):
    global action
    action = 'Change'
    sql = sqlite3.connect('SQL_FILE.db',detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
    cur = sql.cursor()
    button_list = [InlineKeyboardButton(s[0], callback_data=s[0]) for s in cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM ID ORDER BY Name ASC')]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list, n_cols=3))
    update.message.reply_text('ID to change:', reply_markup=reply_markup)

action = None
updater = Updater(token='XXXX:XXXX')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(change_process))

arg_handler = CommandHandler('change', change, pass_args=True)
dispatcher.add_handler(arg_handler)
```

Here is how I want the program to work:

User runs `/change`

Bot returns list of IDs that are able to be changed (using `InlineKeyboardMarkup()` and `build_menu()`

User picks one of the ids

Bot prompts user for new value

The next message that the user sends to the bot will be the value to use

Bot will use the ID the user selected as well as new value and run query to update in database

Bot comments that it updated ID with new value of 'USER VALUE'

The problem I am having is that I can prompt the user to pick the ID and I can prompt the user for input, but I do not know how to do both and use both values in a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to look to [conversation examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples) that `python-telegram-bot` library provides:

- [conversationbot.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py)
- [conversationbot2.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py)
- [nestedconversationbot.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/nestedconversationbot.py)

There are also diagrams that explains the flow of asking data from user.